# QGIS AutoSave Plugins File not Recovering

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have installed the QGIS 3 AutoSave Plugin. It is saving .bak and .bak~ files but when I am trying to recover them by deleting the .bak part from the name, it is just opening the QGIS and not opening the exact project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be resolved by saving directly to the project instead of creating a backup.

Uncheck the Auto save in alternate backup file option in the autoSaver plugin menu.

[image]

Comment: I struggled with this issue too (QGIS 3.16, Win10). But I didn't want to disable _Auto-save-in-alternate-backup-file_ (see answer above) as disabling this option should result in overwriting the current file what is not neccessarely intended by every user. I could solve it  by the way of renaming. I created a separate question with answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408483/qgis-3-16-with-autosaver-plugin-renamed-bak-files-were-not-opened-correctly-or. Note: My solution might be only suitable to Windows, as well as the issue itself might be Windows-specific.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem.  When I deleted the .bak and .bak~ file extensions, that left my file with the .qgz extension instead.  Opening that in QGis just gave me a blank project.  But when I then renamed the extension from .qgz to .qgs, it did work, and I was able to recover what had been lost.  I hope this might work for others too.