# QGIS 3.16 with AutoSaver plugin: Renamed bak-files were not opened correctly or just as a blank project, respectively. (Win 10)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, file-formats, rename

Though my current QGIS-project was not saved in that very moment, yesterday evening my Win 10 decided to run an OS-update and shutted down.
'No problem', I thought because of having installed the AutoSaver plugin, which has created the bak-file as exspected.

According to several forums just renaming the file suffix from *yourfilename.qgz.bak* to *yourfilename.qgs* should be sufficient. But, trying to load the re-suffixed file into QGIS resulted in kind of a blank project (though showing the right filename in the headline of the QGIS-Window). Comparing the autosave-bak-file with an earlier qgs-file (created by 'normal' saving) in the Editor didn't reveal any file error or corruption. So, everything seemed to be allright with the autosaved file.

I was struggling around quite a long time, not finding any answer in the web. (There is a similar thread on stackexchange: [QGIS AutoSave Plugins File not Recovering](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322035/qgis-autosave-plugins-file-not-recovering). But this helped not to solve my specific issue).

As I already found the solution, I will give the answer by myself. It's not very spectacular, but maybe someone else with having the same problem will save some time and nerves.

Answer (score 2):

Let me say first of all: The problem might only occur with Windows, even only with Win 10. I cannot judge this for other OS.

The solution - in my case - was not simply to rename the file in the Win-Explorer, but **open the AutoSave-*bak*-file in the Win-Editor** (any other editor would do it as well, I guess) **and then save it by 'save as ...'** (with precautionarely a new filename and) **with *qgs*-suffix** (not with *txt* of course). 
 Afterwards opening the file in QGis worked as usual, without any problems.

I am not an expert, but background seems to be: Just renaming the suffix with the Explorer will not neccessarely change the file-type information (Explorer --> right-klick on file --> properties). In my case at least, despite having renamed the file to *.qgs* the properties dialog showed the wrong file type: Either *.qgz*, *.bak* or *.qgz.bak*, - I don't remember exactly. But anyway not *.qgs*. So, I guess, this wrong information leads QGIS to read the file the wrong way.
However, the little Editor-detour solved this problem.

Little note for AutoSaver-filetype-beginners: Please be aware to rename the file from *yourfilename.qg**z**.**bak*** to *yourfilename.qg**s*** (not to *yourfilename.qg**z***) as the *bak*-file is based on the qgs-format no matter which format you are basically using. This is also the reason, why the AutoSave-file is 10 or 50 times larger than the origin *qgz* version.